PDF table comparison
I need to get the table from the PDF 'ABIM Laboratory Test Reference Ranges - January 2024' and make the contained values comparable with patient tests. For example, I need the program to indicate if any patient's value falls within the reference range, but I'm not managing to do it concretely.
I tried to turn the PDF into a dictionary and compare the values that way, but there are many values that end up without keys because there are sub-values within the table, such as LDL (low-density lipoprotein) and HDL (high-density lipoprotein) cholesterol
import pdfplumber

def extract_table_from_pdf(pdf_file):
    tables = []
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            table = page.extract_table()
            if table:
                tables.append(table)
    return tables

def convert_table_to_dict(table):
    data_dict = {}
    for row in table[1:]:  
        key = row[0]
        value = row[1]
        if key not in data_dict:
            data_dict[key] = []
        data_dict[key].append(value)
    return data_dict

pdf_file = "exams.pdf"
tables = extract_table_from_pdf(pdf_file)

if tables:
    data_dict = convert_table_to_dict(tables[1])  
    print(data_dict)
else:
    print("error")

"Any suggestion or do I keep the same idea?
